# Nginx Redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to ww

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I'm setting up an Nginx server with an SSL.

The domain with the SSL is `www.mydomain.example`

I want to redirect all requests from:

`http://mydomain.example`, `http://www.mydomain.example`, & `https://mydomain.example` to

`https://www.mydomain.example`

I have the following  server blocks setup currently:

```
server{
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /www/mydomain.example/;

  ssl_certificate /ssl/domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate /ssl/domain.key;
  .
  .
  .
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.example;
  return 301 https://www.mydomain.example$request_uri;
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.example;
  return 301 https://www.mydomain.example$request_uri;
}

server{
  listen ssl 443;
  server_name mydomain.example;
  return 301 https://www.mydomain.example$request_uri;
}
```

This currently does not work, but I don't understand why not. I can get a combination of either HTTP -> HTTPS working or no-www to -> www working, but mixing them as above does not work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The SSL redirect won't work if your SSL certificate doesn't support the non-www domain.
The config is correct but can be reduced to just 1 redirect server

Also don't forget to reload Nginx `sudo service nginx reload`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  # add ssl settings
  return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted and am using it the other way around. Thank you!

Comment: You'll need a separate server with server name `www.domain.com` and liatens to port 80 to do that aditional redirect if you need it.

Comment: This gives me - `nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "443" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:96`

Comment: could u paste that line '96', also your nginx version

Comment: This is also giving me `nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "443"` - Something must have changed.  Using nginx 1.6.2

Comment: I just tested it on that version, it gave me the same too, you can split it into two listen lines `listen 80;` and `listen 443;`

Comment: could someone explain why you need a working certificate for the none-www domain, since, this is a plaine redirection that leads to a new request with the www.domain ?

Comment: @haemse because what the browser does ( roughly ) is it creates a connection to the non www domain ( the url you requested ), gets the certificate and validates it, then if things are ok it would ask for the response ( the redirect ), so you get the certificate failure before getting the redirect response.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady: Ok, so in short, without the cert, it does not even build up a connection ...

Comment: @haemse yea, you'll get the invalid certificate error from the browser

Answer (score 13):

I am late, But you can do like this

```
server{
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.mydomain.example;
  root /www/mydomain.example/;
  
  ssl    on;
  ssl_certificate /ssl/domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate /ssl/domain.key;
  .
  . 
  .
}

server{
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.example mydomain.example;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server{
  listen 443;
  server_name mydomain.example;
  return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Or you can replace `return 301 https://www.$server_name$request_uri;` with  `rewrite   ^ http://www.$server_name$request_uri? permanent;`, both will work.

You also need to set this in google webmaster for better SEO.

Comment: Seems wrong, www.mydomain.com will get replaced to www.www.mydomain.com in the listen 80 block.

Comment: @Feras I have updated the answer, please check. Please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @Feras Great, I am glad this helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work just for https//mydomain.com

Comment: It will redirect https//mydomain.com to https//www.mydomain.com, if did not want to redirect then remove third block.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me for HTTP to HTTPS redirection,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com;

    #For HTTP to HTTPS:

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' )
    {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#If you like to redirect all "http" to "https" then add the following:
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name yourdomain.example;
        server_name www.yourdomain.example;

 if ($scheme = "http")
        {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.example$1 permanent;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a rewrite to send all HTTP traffic to HTTPS:

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server;
 server_name _;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This configuration listens on port 80 as the default server for both IPv4 and IPv6 and
for any hostname. The return statement returns a 301 permanent redirect to the
HTTPS server at the same host and request URI.

Answer (score 0):

Please add two given things on your file.

Code to paste on top:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Code to paste on bottom:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # . . . other code

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

[Source](https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-nginx/)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to fix the problem by redirecting the request URI to `HTTPS` if it was requested with the `HTTP` scheme. But this solution does not work in some conditions.

```
if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

When we type a domain name in the search bar of a browser, it makes a request with the `HTTP` scheme by default. This behavior of the browser is not handled by [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx), but it can be done manually. We have to handle **497** status code by adding `error_page 497 https://$server_name$request_uri;`.

```
error_page 497 https://$server_name$request_uri;

if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

**What does the 497 indicate, and when occur?**

*The 497 HTTP Request Sent to HTTPS Port is used when a client has made an HTTP request to a port that is listening for HTTPS requests specifically.*

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out why HTTP http://example.com wouldn't redirect to HTTPS https://example.com. i had configured it the following way like others have and according to https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html, even after restarting the server with `nginx -s reload && sudo systemctl restart nginx`

/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1m;

    listen                  443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name             www.example.com example.com;
    root                    /var/www/build;
    index                   index.html;
    location / {
                            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

But even though i'm using the latest browsers, the redirection from HTTP to HTTPS only works with the latest in incognito window:

- Firefox: 110.0 (64-bit) (both on Desktop and Mobile)

But **not** with the latest in incognito window even after clear cache and hard reload:

- Brave: Version 1.48.164 Chromium: 110.0.5481.100 (Official Build) (x86_64)
- Chrome: Version 110.0.5481.100 (Official Build) (x86_64)

With Brave and Chrome it just loads the default HTTP page "Welcome to nginx!" from /var/www/html/
index.nginx-debian.html