# SSL on Jelastic and Jetty 9

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jelastic, jetty-9

I created Jelastic environment with Jetty 9. Then I added SSL support - Jelastic created NGinx instance and my solution now available using https and provides certificate. Question is - how to deny access on old non secure way? I mean using ordinary http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to edit the nginx config. to redirect http requests to https.

Example configs:

- [NGINX Redirect http to https and non-www to ww](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106998/nginx-redirect-http-to-https-and-non-www-to-ww)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/250476/how-to-force-or-redirect-to-ssl-in-nginx