# How to do redirection in NGINX

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx

May I ask Where and How to redirect

```
http://domain.com, http://www, https://domain.com
```

to

```
https://www
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NGINX Redirect http to https and non-www to ww](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106998/nginx-redirect-http-to-https-and-non-www-to-ww)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where

In your Nginx config file (the main or vhost depending on your setup)

> How

Try rewrite:

```
    server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    rewrite     ^ https://www.doamin.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

or return:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    return 301 https://www.domain.com$request_uri
}
```

Choice is your when it comes to [Return vs Rewrite](http://think-devops.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/nginx-crumbs.html):

> **REWRITE**
>
> - Only the part of the original url that matches the regex is rewritten.
> - Slower than a Return.
> - Returns HTTP 302 (Moved Temporarily) in all cases, irrespective of permanent.
> - Suitable for temporary url changes.
>
> **RETURN**
>
> - The entire url is rewritten to the url specified.
> - Faster response than rewrite.
> - Returns HTTP 301 (Moved Permanently).
> - Suitable for permanent changes to the url.
> - No need to set permanent.

[Officila Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) on return/rewrite.